# How to detach the tow cable?

Tags: xbox-one, star-wars-battlefront-2015

In *Star Wars: Battlefront*, when flying the snow speeder, I can launch the tow cable (by pressing Y on Xbox One) and circle an AT-AT and kill it just fine. At the end of killing an AT-AT, the "mission control" voice frantically says "Detach the tow cable!", but there is no on-screen prompt as to what button to use or how to detach the tow cable at all.

The first four or five times I killed an AT-AT, I couldn't detach the cable and just kept circling until I crashed into the downed AT-AT and lost a life. Eventually I found through button mashing that turbo boosting forces the cable to detach, but it is a challenge not to turbo boost right into the ground when coming off an AT-AT kill.

**What's the correct way to detach the tow cable on the XBox One?**

Comment: Weird...on PC it detaches by itself as soon as the prompt comes up.

Comment: Second @Miniman on the PC not requiring a keypress. If you crash into the ground, it means that either there was terrain (ie a hill you were next to) or that just before you were successful, your ship indicator went into the red -- you succeeded in dispatching the AT-AT, but failed in getting away clean. I had the same issue for a while before figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The tow cable will automatically detach when you receive the "Success!" message. Anything else is a bug.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to experiment more. I haven't played in a bit so maybe there's an update I need to get.

Answer (score -2):

As long as you successfully stay in the zone it should automatically disconnect, until it does, just keep staying where it tells you. When the voice says, "Detach the Tow Cable!" i usually just press Y(For xbox one) just in case, maybe try that.

Comment: Is this answer in any way different from or more helpful than the existing answer?

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question? But obviously i believe that my answer was also helpful.

Comment: No, that's not a rhetorical question. If you just post the same information again, it's going to get downvoted. Most of the other answers you posted in a flurry are fine. I upvoted at least three of them.  I don't see any reason for posting this answer, though. "Obviously" you did, so what is it?

Comment: I would say this answer is *less* helpful than the existing one. Notice this sentence in my answer: "I couldn't detach the cable and just kept circling until I crashed into the downed AT-AT and lost a life." I was already following your advice when I experienced the problem. By "staying where it tells [me]", I was being forced to crash.

Comment: thank you for voting up the other ones, and for this one i thought GarrettJ just stated a fact, and didn't answer the question, and two of the same answer usually helps people confirm what they think.

Comment: look at it now, i made an edit, thank you for calling my attention to it.